# How mount application log folder in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker for my flask application & here is my application structure
[Application Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuYFd.png)

I just want my logs folder to mount to a different location.
how can I achieve this using docker?

I tried the below command but it's not working for me.

**docker run -v /d/DockerData:/app -p 5001:5000 temp**

**Below is the my Dockerfile**

```
# Pull python Image
FROM python:3.7.6-stretch

# Update Pip
RUN pip install pip --upgrade

# update & install requried packages
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sshpass

# Copy Requirement.txt for installation all python packages
COPY requirements.txt .

# Let's install Python Packages
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: Can you provide your dockerfile?

Comment: @meshkati i added Docker file | can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access your logs directory, you can volume the logs directory anywhere you want, by runnings this:

```
docker run -v /my/absolute/path/in/host:/app/logs -p 5001:5000 temp
```

But for log aggregation, I suggest printing logs in stdout and aggregate them with the proper tools ( like fluentbit etc. )